# My IDE crash every time I Add an XtraReport

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress, xtrareport

Need Help guys
Does anybody know how to fix this problem..I using devexpress and every time I add an xtraReport my IDE crashes.. In some of my projects XtraReport Works fine but so if I make a new one..

My problem is in this certain project when I add an xtrareport my IDE crashes..
Im using VS 2008

error Message :
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A0BC59E) (80131506)

Comment: Ouch! No error message? Did you check your Windows Event Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using the Err utility with this command: err.exe 80131506

Results in:

> for hex 0x80131506 / decimal -2146233082 : COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE
>   corerror.h
>       MessageText:
>
> An internal error happened in the Common Language Runtime's Execution
>   Engine 1 matches found for "80131506"

Its an internal CLR error, you will need to report this to DevExpress. They will require repro steps. If they cant reproduce the crash then they will probably get you to setup adplus and take a Memory Dump when the crash occurs to debug the problem using WinDbg. HTH